# regex to grab a particular group in the string

Tags: regex, grouping, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Hi I wanted to grab a particular group in the regex

Regex that i have is..

```
 \"(myid)\"\:\"((\\\"|[^\"])*)
```

sample string ..

```
 "myid":"123456"
```

I just wanted to grab 123456, can you please suggest

here is what i have tried, i am not sure how to extract Group 2 
https://regex101.com/r/tVDXkY/2

Can you please fix my regex

Comment: Try [`(?<="myid":")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/tVDXkY/3) or even [`(?<="myid":")[^"]+`](https://regex101.com/r/tVDXkY/4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to capture any key and values

```
^\"[^"]+.*(?:\\")?\"\s*:\s*(?:(\d+)|\"([^"]+.*(?:\\")?)\")$
```

https://regex101.com/r/KkSiT4/2 for examples

If you are only looking for myid and a digit use the following:

```
"myid"\s*:\s*"(\d+)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/DTnMRA/1

If the value of myid can contain any character and not just digits use the following:

```
"myid"\s*:\s*"([^"]+.*(?:\\")?)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/icBRCK/1

Comment: i wanted to extra the number 123456 with the regex from this string "myid":"123456"

Comment: The regex in my answer does extract 123456 from the string you just gave me, see first line of https://regex101.com/r/KkSiT4/3 for reference

Comment: from list of examples you have here https://regex101.com/r/KkSiT4/3  i only wanted to match the line 'myid' key & just extract 123456 from it

Comment: Updated the answer for you